# Sort Array of Objects Childs to new Array with Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm programming a small vue.js App and need to convert an array to a new one and sort them.
The array of objects I get from the backend server looks like that:

```js
var arr =
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name1",
    "parents": {
      "someOtherTings": "Test",
      "partentOfParent": {
        "mainId": 10
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Name2",
    "parents": {
      "someOtherTings": "Test",
      "partentOfParent": {
        "mainId": 11
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Name3",
    "parents": {
      "someOtherTings": "Test",
      "partentOfParent": {
        "mainId": 10
      }
    }
  }
]

    console.log(arr)
```

But I need a new array, that is sorted like that:

```js
var newArr =
[
  {
    "mainId": 10,
    "parents": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Name1"
    }
  },
  {
    "mainId": 11,
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Name3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the items with the help of a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, name: "Name1", parents: { someOtherTings: "Test", partentOfParent: { mainId: 10 } } }, { id: 2, name: "Name2", parents: { someOtherTings: "Test", partentOfParent: { mainId: 11 } } }, { id: 3, name: "Name3", parents: { someOtherTings: "Test", partentOfParent: { mainId: 10 } } }],
    result = Array.from(
        array.reduce(
            (m, { id, name, parents: { partentOfParent: { mainId } } }) =>
                m.set(mainId, [...(m.get(mainId) || []), { id, name }]),
            new Map
        ),
        ([mainId, parents]) => ({ mainId, parents })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a combination of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array and then [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it based on the `mainId` value

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name1",
    "parents": {
      "someOtherTings": "Test",
      "partentOfParent": {
        "mainId": 10
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Name2",
    "parents": {
      "someOtherTings": "Test",
      "partentOfParent": {
        "mainId": 11
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Name3",
    "parents": {
      "someOtherTings": "Test",
      "partentOfParent": {
        "mainId": 10
      }
    }
  }
]

const newArr = arr.map(obj => ({
  mainId: obj.parents.partentOfParent.mainId,
  parents: {
    id: obj.id,
    name: obj.name
  },
})).sort((a, b) => b - a);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. With this method I get an array for each, is it possible to merge the parents with the same mainId (like in the example)?